# converting queries to if statement in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to convert these 2 existing select queries:

```
$expiredCheck = "
    SELECT 
        sku_id,
        dealer_id,
        expire_date
    FROM dealerplacetest p
        INNER JOIN skus s
            ON p.sku_id = s.id
    WHERE p.dealer_id = :DEALER
        AND   s.build = :build
        AND   s.cov = :cov
        AND   s.col = :col
         AND   p.expire_date <= date_add(convert(:ship,date), interval 7 day)
";

$validCheck = "
    SELECT 
        sku_id,
        dealer_id,
        expire_date
    FROM dealerplacetest p
        INNER JOIN skus s
            ON p.sku_id = s.id
    WHERE p.dealer_id = :DEALER
        AND   s.build = :build
    AND   s.cov = :cov
        AND   s.col = :col
        AND   p.expire_date > date_add(convert(:ship,date), interval 7 day)
 ";
```

Into one general select like so:

```
$expiredCheck = "
    SELECT 
        sku_id,
        dealer_id,
        expire_date
    FROM dealerplacetest p
        INNER JOIN skus s
            ON p.sku_id = s.id
    WHERE p.dealer_id = :DEALER
        AND   s.build = :build
        AND   s.cov = :cov
        AND   s.col = :col
";
```

And then use my existing bound parameters ($values2) to formulate an if statement that will replace the previously existing expiration date check. Basically I've taken the 2 previous expiration date checks from the query and plugged them into the if statement but it fails the '7' in my day interval. I feel like there may be a different syntax standard to use here but I can't seem to find the proper solution.

I'm trying to create a $count3 variable for the first check and a $count4 variable for the 2nd check.
Here are params and if statement:

```
$values2 = [
        ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
        ":build" => $row2["build"],
        ":cov" => $row2["cov"],
        ":col" => $row2["col"],
        ":ship" => $row2["ship"],
    ];


    $existingRslt = $checkExisting->execute($values2);
    while($existingRow = $checkExisting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if($existingRow["expire_date"] <= date_add(convert(":ship",date), interval 7 day){
            $count3 = $checkExisting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }elseif($existingRow["expire_date"] > date_add(convert(":ship",date), interval 7 day)){
            $count4 = $checkExisting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
```

I'm just trying to consolidate SELECT queries if possible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use convert(":ship",date) in PHP, so use something like this `date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("7 days"));`